# How to assign a keyword to the entire test specification in TestLink?

Tags: keyword, testlink

I want to add a keyword to all the test cases in my test specification. May I know whether there is any easy way of doing it other than adding the keyword to each test case manually?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the start page on the left side there is an option "Assign Keywords". If you click on that you see the test suites. Instead of expand these you can click on a test suite then select the keyword and assign it. Aaaand it's done